# How to use the listen_ports_facts module, ansible

Tags: ansible

Using ansible I want to check in which port tomcat is running, of course I think there are different ways to do it, but I found this ansible module

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/listen_ports_facts_module.html

And  I would like to use it, but according to the examples, I do not know how to use it.

I mean if I setup

```
gather_facts: true
```

And run the task

```py
  - name: List TCP ports
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.tcp_listen }}"
```

I got the error

```py
TASK [discover-servers : List TCP ports] *******************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/A78252689/sap_bo/roles/discover-servers/tasks/tomcat_servers.yml:4
fatal: [2a00:da9:2:21ca:111:0:426:2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'tcp_listen'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/A78252689/sap_bo/roles/discover-servers/tasks/tomcat_servers.yml': line 4, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: List TCP ports\n    ^ here\n"}
```

If I set up the task exactly how it is in the example, I got an error in the first task ***Gather facts on listening ports***

```
TASK [discover-servers : include_tasks] ********************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/A78252689/sap_bo/roles/discover-servers/tasks/main.yml:4
fatal: [2a00:da9:2:21ca:111:0:426:2]: FAILED! => {"reason": "no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/A78252689/sap_bo/roles/discover-servers/tasks/tomcat_servers.yml': line 4, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Gather facts on listening ports\n    ^ here\n"}
```

So, do you know how to use the module listen_ports_facts?
Thanks in advance for your kind support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gather_facts` stage of your playbook runs uses the `setup` module. It does not run `listen_ports_facts`, so if you don't run the module explicitly you won't have those facts available.

From the docs, the `listen_ports_module` creates the following facts:

- `tcp_listen`
- `udp_listen`

Using Ansible 2.9.2, the following works just fine:

```
---
- gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - listen_ports_facts:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ tcp_listen }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ udp_listen }}"
```

If you're trying to run the `listen_ports_facts` module and you're getting the error "no action detected in task", it may be that you're running an older version of Ansible that doesn't have the `listen_ports_facts` module.  It first showed up in version 2.9.

Comment: I've got empty `tcp_listen` and `udp_listen` until I add `become: true` to `listen_ports_facts` task